# chart js, multi stack bar graph, react js

Tags: reactjs

[image]

I am trying to create a flocked stacked bar chart like the one shown in image, please provide resources or code in sandbox for it

Comment: Would you mind sharing your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This site](https://apexcharts.com/react-chart-demos/column-charts/stacked/) shows class components snippets to do what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: here it's given horizontal, how do i make it verticle?

Comment: I just updated the reference site. Hopefully, you can use it now

Comment: It was a matter of changing `yaxis` for `xaxis`.

Comment: this is for Apex charts, isnt there one for charts.js.2 https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-chartjs-2